# Firefox extension to save highlights with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, annotations

I'm looking for something specific: a Firefox extension that will allow me to highlight text (i.e. add a yellow background to web text and save the highlight across sessions) using a keyboard shortcut.

I use caret browsing in Firefox on OSX to read articles online, and I'd like to be able to save highlights (and even annotations) using only the keyboard.

Does such an extension exist?

Update: [TextMarker!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/textmarker/) kinda sorta does this, but does not save highlights across sessions, which makes it pointless.

Comment: I would assume that's hard to implement, because websites are very dynamic and could have changed between browsing sessions. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Would this work? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/highlights/ I guess it could work, but seems like it's outdated :\

Comment: Clip the page into evernote or something?  Apply your highlights in Evernote?

Comment: This would be difficult to implement well. It would either have to be very hit and miss by making the reference to the highlighted test explicit (making it pretty much worthless because of unreliability), it could make smart decisions based on the current DOM structure at the time of highlighting or it could be very resource intensive and search through each node on page load (or mix'n'match with 2). This seems like a XYZ problem. Why do you want to do this? Wouldn't it be easier to simply use an extension that saves notes based on the URL (which you could add to using highlight->"Make note")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look into the extension called pentadactyl . It is a caret browsing addon , which allows you to yank specific texts which is highlighted , save them , call them across sessions.

[enter link description here](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/)